# Running make command throws issue error: ‘crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, makefile, scope, header-files, libsodium

I am running the make command as suggested by the documentation, but i am getting below error:

```
./include/mega/crypto/sodium.h:38:40: error: ‘crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES’ was not declared in this scope
   38 |     static const int SEED_KEY_LENGTH = crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES;
```

Below is code snippet from sodium.h

```
#ifndef SODIUM_H
#define SODIUM_H 1

#include </include/mega/crypto/sodium.h>
#include <vector>


namespace mega {

class PrnGen;

/**
 * @brief Asymmetric cryptographic signature using EdDSA with Edwards 25519.
 */
class MEGA_API EdDSA
{
public:
    static const int SEED_KEY_LENGTH = crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES;
```

I am not sure why, I am getting this issue. Where should I define crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES.
Should it be a part of the library which must be installed?

Comment: That error message has nothing to do with `make`.  It is the compiler complaining that the code it is trying to compile is ill-formed.